# VSTS - Jenkins PHPUnit results

Tags: jenkins, azure-devops

I am trying to the test results form my PPHUnit test to show up in VSTS.

Jenkins is running the tests with this command:

```
php vendor/bin/phpunit --log-junit results/phpunit/phpunit.xml -c phpunit.xml
```

The results are correctly being generated at the `$WORKSPACE/results/phpunit/phpunit.xml` path.

Unfortunately I am unable to get them to show up in VSTS. I added the "Publish Test Results" task to the build process.

The "Test results files" option is set to `/results/phpunit/phpunit.xml` and the search folder to `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`. The task always ends with this error:

> ##[warning]No test result files matching /results/phpunit/phpunit.xml
>   were found.

I also tried `results/phpunit/phpunit.xml` and `**/results/phpunit/phpunit.xml` same problem though.

Comment: Is it in source directory (e.g. xx/1/s/results/xxx) or artifact folder (e.g. xx/1/a/results/xxx)? Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive? (Set system.debug variable to true and queue build) On the other hand, you can try it with **\phpunit.xml

Comment: From the debug log I can see that the directory that holds the result file is not being added to the list of directories. Not sure why that is.

Comment: It looks like it only scans the data that was in the commit. The result is obviusly created after that and is located on the jenkins server.

Comment: What's the result file in? What do you mean the directory is not being added to the list of directories? How it is related to jenkins server?